# Splash screen displays white screen and then black before it sets the menu page

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, splash-screen

my app has a splash screen with an animated logo(using a thread) and then a menu page is displayed.

Now I want to do some background activity in my splash screen. That is I want to convert some images to string etc.

I have placed the code to do this in my onCreate() function. But the problem is that instead of splash screen i see a blank white screen and then a black screen. Then after sometime the menu page is displayed as usual.

If i comment the code of the background processing it functions perfectly. Also the background code is working correctly. Only they are not working properly together. There are no errors in the logcat and I am unable to know what is wrong.

**Java Code of Splash Screen**

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

protected int _splashTime = 10000; 

private Thread splashTread;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //MakeFolder(); 
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

         MakeFolder();   
    ImageView IM =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    final Animation mobianim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mobianim);

    IM.setAnimation(mobianim);
    mobianim.setDuration(1000);

    animate();
  //  AnimateLogo();


     final Splash sPlashScreen = this; 

    // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
    splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {                   
                synchronized(this){
                    wait(_splashTime);

                }


            } catch(InterruptedException e) {} 
            finally {
                finish();

                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(sPlashScreen, MenuPg.class);
                startActivity(i);


               // stop();
            }
        }
    };

    splashTread.start();



      /* 
              **Code for doing background things**

       */

}

public void MakeFolder(){
    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder");

    if(!direct.exists())
     {
         if(direct.mkdir()){ //directory is created;

     }
    }
    }

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        synchronized(splashTread){
            splashTread.notifyAll();
        }
    }
    return true;
}


public void animate(){
        ImageView IV1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


        AlphaAnimation alphaAmin = new AlphaAnimation(0,1);
        IV1.setAnimation(alphaAmin);
        alphaAmin.setDuration(5000);

}
}
```

Comment: Could you try removing the synchronize(this) part? What you are doing does not require synchronization anyway. You also could just post a delayed runnable on the UI thread that does the same (finishing, starting next activity). You could post it on your imageView like this: IV1.postDelayed(runnable, _splashTime);

Comment: Off topic, but: http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/

Answer (score 0):

Is your *Code for doing background things* running in another thread or is it part of the UI Thread?
Because your animation wont be shown until your onCreate method finishes, so that could be.

Also you could use startAnimation(animation) on the imageviews so they start in that moment.